# How do I access the host application's web.config file from a class library/assembly?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, configuration

I'm creating a class library that will be used in a web application. One of the things that happens in one of the assembly classes is that it hits a database. Normally, when I do this from a service, the connection string gets extracted from the web.config file. With the class library, I'm not so sure how that's going to work the same way. Any suggestions?

Right now, I tried putting my normal config call in the assembly:

```
protected readonly string _utiConnStr =
 System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UTI"].ConnectionString;
```

It pukes, saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I tried it, it failed. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance if I want mail settings:

```
 //open the webconfig
 Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"~/web.config");

 // Get mail settings
 mailSettings = webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

Comment: so really what is happening here is that I can specify the location of the configuration file that I want to read from, directly inside the assembly?

Comment: i was having some mapping issues with this. I used var configMgr = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
            this._utiConnStr = configMgr.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["UTI"].ConnectionString; and it still failed. I ran VS in administrator and it worked fine. Apparently IIS will have the appropriate rights to work.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do impersonation in your case, have the IIS user impersonate a user with db access.